# Can't define the 'const' constructor because the field 'mylist' is initialized with a non-constant value

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I found a problem, because I just learned the newest flutter, whereas what I learned was the old version of flutter.

when I make myList variable separate from Children

Errors:

```
Can't define the 'const' constructor because the field 'mylist' is initialized with a non-constant value.
Try initializing the field to a constant value, or removing the keyword 'const' from the constructor. [Ln 8, Col 3]
```

```
Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.
Try making all of the fields final, or removing the keyword 'const' from the constructor. [Ln 9, Col 9]
```

Script :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  List<Widget> mylist = [
            Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List View"),
        ),        
        body: ListView(
          //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: mylist,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help and explain the details of the problem and references

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `const` keyword since `MyApp()` isn't a `const`ant:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  List<Widget> mylist = [
    Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List View"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: mylist,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For an explanation see:
[What is the difference between the "const" and "final" keywords in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431055/what-is-the-difference-between-the-const-and-final-keywords-in-dart)

> If the value you have is computed at runtime (new DateTime.now(), for
> example), you can not use a const for it. However, if the value is
> known at compile time (const a = 1;), then you should use const over
> final. There are 2 other large differences between const and final.
> Firstly, if you're using const inside a class, you have to declare it
> as static const rather than just const. Secondly, if you have a const
> collection, everything inside of that is in const. If you have a final
> collection, everything inside of that is not final.

Comment: Previously I tried to like that but the error was in widget_test.dart

Comment: @TriAminRidho It's fine, you can just remove it from there too (or ignore it). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71651959/error-in-const-myapp-in-widget-test-dart-file

Comment: thank you for helping, the program was successful there was no error but before debug there was a notification "Build errors exist in your project". but i still "debug anyway" it works.

I was still not satisfied so I tried the previous version so I could learn with the appropriate instructions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, because the `mylist` is mutable it means that it can be changed, and re-assignable, and the class which contains it can't be const anymore.

a `const` class is a class whose members are also `const` ( constant ).

so if you're willing to re-assign the `mylist` value in your code, then you need to remove the `const` keyword from your class constructor like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key}); // removed const
    List<Widget> mylist = [
 // ...
```

Comment: if I use 'final'.

there is still a problem in the 'const' section
error:
Can't define the 'const' constructor because the field 'myList' is initialized with a non-constant value.

Comment: sorry, you're right, using final won't solve it, since Container can't be const also, I didn't notice it.